# What is the best data structure/algorithm for data requiring bidirectional 1 to N mappings?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I've got a reasonable (though rusty) background in algorithms and mathematics, and modest proficiency in Python and C.  I can see sorta how to do this, but it's non-trivial, and gets more complicated every time I prototype it.  I come before the collective for it's wisdom hoping for an elegant solution I'm not seeing.  I think there's some sort of network or graph variant that might be apropos, but it's not clicking.  And it's not a homework assignment :-).

I have three sets of data, A, B & C.  Each element in A is a string, each element in B is an int and each C is a collection of metadata (dates, times, descriptions, etc.).  There will be, potentially, thousands if not millions of elements in each set (though not soon).

Every A will map to zero or more items in B.  Conversely, each element in B will map to zero or more items in A.  Every item in A and B will have an associated C (possibly empty) which might be shared with other A's and/or B's.

Given an A, I need to report on all B's that it maps to.  I further then need to report all A's that those B's map to, as well as all C's associated with what was found.  I also need to be able to do the converse (given a B, report associated A's, B's and C's).

I understand there are some fairly pathological possibilities in here, and I'll need to detect loops (depth detection should work fine), etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: If this will be in-memory, why not simple nested dictionaries and/or lists?

Comment: Lists and Dictionaries got very complex, very quickly.  It's clearly doable, but I thought there had to be something more elegant.

Comment: If you're going to use graphs, use the networkx package: http://networkx.lanl.gov/ You can have items from A and B be your nodes, and you can attach attributes to connecting edges. You'll then get a bunch of the algorithms for free: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.html .

Comment: Yes, I've found the networkx work, and it's remarkable and comprehensive.  Now I just need to remember my graph algorithms to implement.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

what first comes to mind for me would be a [Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29) or [Directed Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)

Each element in the data sets could be a node and the edges would represent the mappings.  You could write your specific implementation to provide helper methods for the things you know you're going to need to do, like get all Bs that a given A element maps to

UPDATE: i didn't notice you tagged the question graph-algorithm already which I assume means you already thought of a graph data structure

Comment: Yes, I think a graph is the right answer.  I'm having some difficulty bridging the concept to implementation.  Thanks for confirming I was roughly on the right track.